# How to change the counter of problems or questions and solutions to start from any number?

Tags: exsheets

I have a homework. The problems chosen by the lecturer are often not in arithmetic sequence so I have to change the problem counter (and its solution counter) manually.

```
\documentclass[preview,varwidth,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets
{
    solution/print=true, % default false
}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}
How to change  the counter of problems or questions and solutions to start from any number?
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
I don't know the counter name!
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\setcounter{question}{<whatever>}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\setcounter{question}{99}
```

You could guess it is `question` or it may be documented or you could look in the log where every counter allocation is logged:

```
\c@question=\count146
```

Comment: I had no idea one can find counter info in the log.  +1